# Ruby on Rails - "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" when using acts_as_votable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror, acts-as-votable

I'm trying to create a Reddit clone in which users and upvote and downvote posts. I've installed and ran the necessary migrations for the *acts_as_votable* gem (https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable):

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :trackable, :validatable
    ...
    acts_as_voter
end

# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    ...
    acts_as_votable
end
```

I should also mention that I'm using single table inheritance to simplify working with each type of post:

```
# app/models/text_post.rb
class TextPost < Post
...
end

# app/models/link.rb
class Link < Post
...
end
```

I've tried to implement upvote/downvote functionality (http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/votable):

```
# config/routes.rb
...
resources :posts do
    member do 
        put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
        put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
    end
    ...
end
...

# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :index
    ...
    def upvote
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.upvote_by current_user
        redirect_to :back
    end

    def downvote
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.downvote_by current_user
        redirect_to :back
    end
end

# app/views/posts/index.html.erb
...
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    ...
    <%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put do %>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
    <% end %>
    ...
    <%= link_to dislike_post_path(post), method: :put do %>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
    <% end %>
    ...
<% end %>
...
```

But when I try to vote on a post, I get

## NoMethodError in PostsController#upvote

**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

on this line in my controller:

```
@post.upvote_by current_user
```

Even if I attempt it manually in the console without using *current_user*, I get the same error:

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.first
...
irb(main):002:0> post = Post.first
...
irb(main):003:0> post.upvote_by user
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):3
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

I'm unsure if there is something wrong with my code or if it's perhaps a compatibility issue as I'm using Rails **5.2.0** and the GitHub page for *acts_as_votable* lists only **5.0** and **5.1** as supported versions.

If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see `upvote_from` method in the controller. Do you mean `upvote_by`?

Comment: You're right, it should say `upvote_by`. I'll edit it.

Comment: Which version of the gem are you using?

Comment: 0.11.1, the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upvote_by` seems to be an alias of `vote_up`, maybe you are not using the same gem version from the tutorial?

https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/599995f7ec5aa0f8a04312768fc956e9003d32d4/lib/acts_as_votable/votable.rb#L15

Try using `vote_up` instead, since it looks like the original method, it should work on versions where the `upvote_by` alias was not set.

Comment: Using `@post.vote_up current_user` returns the same error.

Comment: You were right about the gem version, though! I changed mine to the one the tutorial uses (0.10.0) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Its been a long time but I think you might not have been setting your post in the controller.

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#upvote
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The error is telling you that you are trying to vote on a class that has not been set. you have to set the class in the controller

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
```